# Running parallel multiprocessing python scripts with slurm

Tags: python-multiprocessing, slurm

I'm trying to run simultaneously using slurm a python script that internally parallelizes a process using multiprocessing. The goal of the python script is to solve a stochastic differential equation several times in order to have enough statistics for the analysis. To speed up the process, I split the repetitions into 4 child processes using multiprocessing. On the other hand, to use all my resources I'm trying to run this script simultaneously several times, with different input parameters (i.e. different conditions for the equation). Right now, I'm using one node with 16 CPUs, so I want to run the code 4 times simultaneously assigning 4 CPUs to each set of conditions such that 4x4=16.

My implementation for slurm is a batch script `run.sh` that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH -N 1
#SBATCH -n 16
#SBATCH --time=10:00:00 

module purge > /dev/null 2>&1

eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate my_environment


srun --exclusive -n 1 python script.py 0.95 1 1 0 1 0 > nohup1.out 2>&1 & 
srun --exclusive -n 1 python script.py 0.955 1 1 0 1 0 > nohup2.out 2>&1 & 
srun --exclusive -n 1 python script.py 0.96 1 1 0 1 0 > nohup3.out 2>&1 & 
srun --exclusive -n 1 python script.py 0.965 1 1 0 1 0 > nohup4.out 2>&1 & 
srun --exclusive -n 1 python script.py 0.97 1 1 0 1 0 > nohup5.out 2>&1 & 
srun --exclusive -n 1 python script.py 0.975 1 1 0 1 0 > nohup6.out 2>&1 & 

wait
```

To run this batch script I'm using `sbatch run.sh`. Note that in the example code I have 6 combinations of parameters (I plan to have even more for the real case). I was expecting slurm to run the first 4 based on the available resources and proceed with the next 2 when finishing. However, it sends all the scripts at the same time. I suspect this is because of the flag `--exclusive`. However, when I remove it, it just runs the script one by one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it like this, it could be helpful for other people.

```
#!/bin/bash

module purge > /dev/null 2>&1

eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)"
conda activate <my_environment>

A=1.0
B=1.0
C=0.0
D=0.0
E=1.0

for F in 0.95 0.955 0.96 0.965 0.97 0.975
do
  out_name=A$A-B$B-C$C-D$D-E$E-F$F
  JOBNAME=<custom_job_name>
  srun -n 1 -c 4 --time=100:00:00 --job-name=$JOBNAME python scripts/msd_fle_two_baths_parallel.py $F $A $B $C $D $E > nohup$out_name.out 2>&1 &
done
```

Running the script as `./run.sh` slurm allocates the jobs based on the available resources. The flag `-n 1` assigns the task only to one job, and `-c 4` assigns 4 CPUs to each job, allowing Python's multiproccess.

I parameterized all the inputs from A to E, to generalize it, and put the line to run the script inside a for loop sweeping along F to avoid redundancy.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to do a thing called parameter sweep. There are wonderful tools to do this instead of handling it yourself using a lot of `srun`, which might not work as far as I know. You could try the following:

- [Facebook's Hydra with joblib plugin](https://hydra.cc/docs/plugins/joblib_launcher/)

This gives you a lot of control but requires careful planning. You need to use a separate logger such as python logger or mlflow logger depending on things you want to save. You can define the number of jobs in the config file which makes your life way easier. However, if your job exceeds the nodes timelimit (mostly 2 days) then you need to manually find which one failed. So be careful.

- [Use wandb sweep manager](https://docs.wandb.ai/guides)

This gives you little less control but it is mostly out of the box. There is an online server which assigns sweep parameters to each child jobs. This makes it very easy to restart failed jobs.

You need to explore both and choose a suitable tool.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Currently, I'm using a slurm-based cluster without many user rights to do more magic. But I'll keep this for future tasks.

Comment: yes, I have used them on HPC with slurm scheduler. they are simply python package, just use `pip install`. No need of admin rights. I saw your solution,  which is very neat. But if you want to have more control without doing a lot of hardcoding, you might try my solutions.